# UIWindow loses rootviewcontroller after launch

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow, appdelegate

My application has a UIWindow with a correctly set rootview controller.  I know this because I check for the rootViewController after it is set (in the app delegate), and all is well.

Once My app launches, everything works fine.  My issue is that the rootview controller is no longer set correctly on the UIWindow when I check in the 'main' view.

My app works fine.. so what is the issue you may be wondering... well, I am trying to implement AdColony (video advertising), an they need to grab the UIWindow's rotviewcontroller to dislplay their ad.  When they check for the rootviewcontroller... it is null.

I have added code to check as well.. and the rootviewcontroller is null.

How can my UIWindow lose its pointer to the rootviewcontroller?  I need help understanding how the UIWindow architecture works.

Thanks

code that checks for UIWindow's visible controller (the below code returns nil for the viewcontrollers value.

```
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController* rootViewController = [window rootViewController];

    [self getVisibleViewControllerChild:rootViewController];


- (UIViewController*)getVisibleViewControllerChild:(UIViewController*)viewController {

UIViewController* visibleViewController = nil;

if(!viewController) {
    NSLog(@"nil");
    return nil;
}

if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)viewController;
    viewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;
    NSLog(@"viewcontroller is nav controller");
}

while (visibleViewController == nil) {

    if (viewController.modalViewController == nil) {
        visibleViewController = viewController;
        NSLog(@"visibleViewController = %@", visibleViewController);
    } else {

        if ([viewController.modalViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)viewController.modalViewController;
            viewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;
            NSLog(@"modal 1");
        } else {
            viewController = viewController.modalViewController;
            NSLog(@"modal 2");
        }
    }

}

return visibleViewController;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really figure out what you're trying to do with this code, but the method keyWindow seems to be returning nil, so rootViewController will also be nil. I'm not sure why that's true, but you can get the rootViewController with (I assume you're doing this from a view controller):

```
self.view.window.rootViewController
```

Comment: Ok, you have me going in the right direction.  I apologize for the vague question.. I am a bit confused by what is going on.  My issue seems to be that my visibleViewController is somehow getting set to nil.  The rootViewController is correctly set to my UINavigationController.  What's very weird is.. if I present a modal controller (like the native tweet composition view), then that is dismissed, by visibleViewController is set correctly.  Once the view is refreshed.. it is nil again.

Comment: @mtb, you say in your question that AdColony needs to grab the root view controller, so I don't understand what you're trying to do with visibleViewController. Also you call getVisibleViewControllerChild: which returns a UIViewController, but you never assign the return value to any variable or property.

Comment: This code was just to check if a visibleViewController exists.  When My app launches, the rootcontroller is set correctly to the navigation controller.  But the visibleViewController is nil.  I set it correctly in the app delegate, and the app works fine.. but because the visibleViewcontroler is nil, AdColony (and Facebook feeds) do not function correctly.  The very weird thing is that after I use the native tweet composition modal view.. the visibleViewController is populated correctly.  I am somehow corrupting the visibleViewController when I enter the app... I just have no idea how..?

Comment: ok, so my solution to this was to use "[self.view.window makeKeyWindow];" when I needed to ensure that the main window was set correctly.  How big of a hack is this?

Comment: @mtb, sees ok to me, but did the way I posted not work to get you the root view controller?